# How do i filter my array of hashes to output only the hashes I would like?

Tags: arrays, ruby, select, hash

So far I have figured out how to sort my hashes by a specification of cohort:

```
bycohort = students.sort_by { |v| v[:cohort] }
```

This method allows me to sort my hashes in my input method.Once printed with the print_with_index method, it outputs this to the screen:

```
1. Penny (january cohort)
2. Nicole (may cohort)
3. Ali (may cohort)
4. Jack (november cohort)
5. John (november cohort)
6. Olu (november cohort)
7. Henry (september cohort)
8. Olivia (september cohort)
```

I use a separate method for printing the array of hashes:

```
 def print_with_index(students)
   students.each_with_index do |students, index|
     index_plus_one = index + 1 
       puts "#{index_plus_one}. #{students[:name]} (#{students[:cohort]} cohort)"
   end
 end
```

I would like to remove all hashes other that those with a November cohort. How do I do this as I am stumped.

Comment: You could write `students.each.with_index(1) { |s,i| puts "#{i} .." }`. See [Enumerator#with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
students.select! { |student| student[:cohort] == :november }
```

if `student[:cohort]` is a symbol. Otherwise, if that is a string

```
students.select! { |student| student[:cohort] == 'november' }
```

Or, this works for both

```
students.select! { |student| student[:cohort].to_sym == :november }
```

Comment: Wow so simple. Thank you so much.

Comment: My pleasure Sir ;)

Comment: Note that this literally _removes_ the non-november entries from the hash passed in to the method. That means if the caller of the method was holding on to that hash and planned to use it for other things, later, you've modified the hash they were holding. If you just want to only _print_ the november entries, without modifying the original hash, use `select` instead of `select!`, like, `students.select {|student| ... }.each_with_index do | student, index | ... end`